# Please explain this inconsistency between using arr[2nd parameter] vs firstPrameter in forEach (JS)

Tags: javascript

```
var x =["a", "b", "c"]
x.forEach(function(element, i){
x[i] = x[i].toUpperCase();
})
console.log(x) // ["A", "B", "C"] what I want

var x =["a", "b", "c"]
x.forEach(function(element, i){
element = element.toUpperCase();
})

console.log(x)// ["a", "b", "c"] not what I want
```

Shouldn't each element mean x[i] exactly?  Why then am I getting inconsistent answers?

Comment: `var i = 0, j = i; j = 1;` what is `i`?

Comment: LoL. @PaulS. Nice explanation man. I took a moment to understand. I don't think that's easy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the below code:

```
var x =["a", "b", "c"]
x.forEach(function(element, i){
  element = element.toUpperCase();
})
```

You are making changes to `element`, which dies after the next `})`. Moreover, it doesn't affect the `x`, as it is a readonly property.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't each element mean x[i] exactly?

No, it's just a copy, with the same value. If elements of the `x` array were non-primitive types (objects) then yes, those would have been passed by reference and changes to `element` would be reflected in `x[i]` too. But in your case of primitive values (strings) elements are just copies of values in `x`.

Comment: *"If elements of the x array were non-primitive types (objects) then yes, those would have been passed by reference"* No, that's not correct. Objects are represented *as* references, but this is different from passing *by* reference. It's true that objects are mutable and because of reference representation you can achieve a similar affect, but `element = ....` will never work, whether `element` is an object or not.

Comment: Well of course `but element = .... will never work`. I meant *"changes to element would be reflected in x[i] too"*. Maybe I was not precise saying about references, but to me difference between real reference and "representation as references" is very subtle.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a [primitive value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Primitive_values) and not the object.

```js
var x = ["a", "b", "c"];
x.forEach(function(element, i, array) { // array is the calling array x
    array[i] = array[i].toUpperCase();
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(x, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```